# как удалить картинку js?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

```
var image1=new Image(); // добавление картинки

image1.src="3/2.jpg";  // расположение начального фона

function  q1(){ // начальный фон
ctx.drawImage(image1,0,0);  // прогрузка начального фона в координатах 0 0

}

image1.onload=q1; // когда картинки загрузится 




//Когда нажимаю на кнопку картинка должна удалятся 

btn2=document.createElement( 'BUTTON'); // создание кнопки
btn2.id='cmd2'; // её id 
btn2.textContent ='удалить картинку'; // её текст
document.body.appendChild(btn2); // нужно чтобы добавилось 
btn2.onclick=function(){ // функция при клике на неё 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение вашей задачи:

```js
 var src = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4deff273cbbbb0e3a73938e37697036f?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',
 id = 'myImage';

 function createButtons() {
  // First button / Generate image
  var buttonGenerate = document.createElement('BUTTON'),
  buttonDelete = document.createElement('BUTTON');

  buttonGenerate.textContent = 'Add';
  buttonDelete.textContent = 'Delete';

  var body = document.querySelector('body');

  body.appendChild(buttonGenerate);
  body.appendChild(buttonDelete);

  buttonGenerate.addEventListener('click', createImgElement);
  buttonDelete.addEventListener('click', deleteImgElemet);
 }

 function createImgElement() {
  var image = document.createElement("IMG");
  
  image.id = id;
  image.src = src;
  // image.alt = alt;

  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(image);
 }

 function deleteImgElemet() {
  var image = document.getElementById(id);

  if (image != undefined) {
   image.remove();
  } else {
   console.log('Image is undefined');
  }
 }

 createButtons();
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>Hello!</h1>
</body>
```

Только картинка не подгружается, попробуйте вставить код в вашу локальную среду разработки, там должно работать все как часы.

Comment: Когда нажимаю на кнопку картинка должна удалятся  дополнил вопрос

Comment: Давайте разберемся. Вам нужно добавить кнопку, при которой будет удаляться элемент `img`? Или же вам нужно создать две кнопки, при нажатие на одну кнопку `img` будет создаваться, а при нажатие на другую `img` будет удаляться?

Comment: две кнопки, при нажатие на одну кнопку img будет создаваться, а при нажатие на другую img будет удаляться.вот так

Comment: @СергейАлександров я вас понял, одну минуту...

Comment: В ответах надо писать ответы, а не вопросы задавать

Comment: @Air простите, к сожалению я не мог задать комментарий, а дабы уточнить вопрос, мне пришлось написать в ответы...

Comment: Странно.... Репутация позволяет.. Обратись к админам...

Comment: @Air совершенно верно, но я получил так сказать "повышение" после того, как задал здесь вопрос, в ответы =(

Comment: Тогда правь ответ, если понял вопрос автора, а то схлопочешь минусов... Я свой убрал... Но тревогу нет, на случай если не будет ответа, админ удалит ответ

Comment: Интересно если я такой код добавляю в css то кнопки исчезают после нажатия показать картинку #myImage{
   `position: absolute;
top: 0px; 
left:0px;
}`

Comment: @СергейАлександров потому что картинка их закрывает. И это уже другой вопрос. Если я решил ваш вопрос, буду благодарен за отметку "Решено".